# How can I delete rows in the text?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Consider a text.txt file having the form

```
25 1 4 5 2 19 38

21 0 8 8 7 7 61

<clus scale = "125"> 1 3 2</clus>

25 3 1.63 123 56 12 38

21 123 12.3 12.1 1.5 2.67 3.77

<clus scale = "227"> 5 6 2</clus>
```

How can I leave only numeric (and empty) rows using the terminal, i.e. to convert a file to

```
25 1 4 5 2 19 38

21 0 8 8 7 7 61

25 3 1.63 123 56 12 38

21 123 12.3 12.1 1.5 2.67 3.77
```

Comment: How do you define "numeric"? Your output also has empty lines. Do you want to keep all lines that have only numbers and whitespace and all empty lines?

Comment: @terdon : yes, that's what I would like to have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `grep`:

```
grep '^[0-9. ]*$' text.txt
```

or to also exclude empty lines from the match, use

```
grep -E '^[0-9. ]+$' text.txt
```

This will select lines with numbers, dot and space.
You can also reverse the pattern, by excluding lines with for example `<` using `grep -v`:

```
grep -v "<" text.txt
```

Comment: Note that your second `grep` won't exclude lines with only whitespace, it will only exclude lines with no characters. And you might want to include `-` for negative numbers.